# Magento 2 stable vs development

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Can I know the different between magento2 stable version which we can download at https://magento.com/ and development version at github. Which can I use for development of new CMS site and to do customizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends ;)

No really. You can actually also download the stable from github if you choose the latest release for example.

The difference is that the develop branch has all the fancy new features but is far more likely to have bugs or even break the complete shop instance.

So my recommendation would be to start development with the stable version (especially when you are just starting with magento2).

Then if you find a bug or miss a feature you can look it up in develop, it may have already been fixed/added there.

Comment: Thanks @David. Most of forums and tutorials pointing out installing using magento2 development version and I was confused with those 2. You have cleared me.

Comment: I install Magento 2.3.4 using Github, any difficulties will i face in the future during version update? thanks @David Verholen

Answer (score 2):

Magento has three types of installations, described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/continue.html

1. Download
2. Composer
3. Github

> Which can I use for development of new CMS site and to do customizations?

The "composer" ("System Integrator") installation is the best fit, but if it is too technical for you, choose "download" or ("Easy Installation")

Github installation is targeted at **contributors** who want to develop Magento itself, not a custom site.

Comment: interesting. that means composer installation and git clone gives you two different code base  (whether contributors can see more files/sections)?

Comment: TBH I don't know if there are more files but at least the directory structures differ (`vendor` vs `app`/`lib`)

Comment: @FabianSchmengler I install Magento 2.3.4 using Github, any difficulties will i face in the future during version update? thanks

Comment: @zus I repeat, the github installation is not meant to run Magento in production

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Noted, Thank you.